# Get json from one view by calling it from another view

Tags: python, flask

I have a view that returns JSON data.  I want to get that data from another view as well, so I tried calling the JSON view from it.  However, a `Response` was returned rather than the JSON data.  How can I call one view from another view and get the data?

```
@app.route('/promoters/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_promoter(id):
    ...

>>> get_promoter(3)
<Response 440 bytes [200 OK]>
```

Answer (score 3):

The decorator of a view-function can convert your return-value in a  [Response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Response) object depending on it's type (more information about these rules check out [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#about-responses)). The json data is stored in `r.response` where `r` is the `Response` object.

The better solution is to create a separate function, which returns the json data, which can be called from two different view-functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a decorator for your views to handle this:

```
from flask import jsonify
from functools import wraps

def jsonify_or_raw(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        raw = False
        if "raw" in kwargs:
            raw = kwargs["raw"]
            del kwargs["raw"]
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return jsonify(result) if not raw else result
    return wrapper
```

You would use the decorator like so:

```
@app.route('/promoters/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
@jsonify_or_raw
def get_promoter(id):
  return {"your data": "goes here"}
```

The decorator will handle wrapping your data in a response via `flask.jsonify` -- but you can also get the data from another view by doing the following:

```
@app.route('/some_page', methods=['GET'])
def some_page():
    promoter = get_promoter(1, raw=True)
    ...
```

Comment: just for clarification, in the last snippet, if I write `jsonify=True` then it will return json object?

Answer (score 0):

Your view has `return jsonify(...)` at the end of it.  `jsonify` returns a `Response` with JSON data, it doesn't return the raw data directly.  You could re-parse the JSON data from the response object, or you could separate the function that generates data from the view that returns a response.

```
from flask import json
r = get_promoter(id)
data = json.loads(r.data, encoding=r.charset))
```

```
# or separate the data from the view
def get_promoter(id):
    return json.dumps(...)

@app.route(...)
def promoter(id):
    return jsonify(**get_promoter(id))

@app.route(...)
def other_view():
    promoter = get_promoter(400617)
    ...
```

---

Other views may return other types of data.  `jsonify` happens to return a `Response` object, but other valid return values are strings (from `render_template`, for example) and tuples.  Any of these will be turned into `Responses` when Flask is handling a request, but when just calling the view functions they return whatever they return, which *might happen to be* a `Response`.